# Select from table A if not exist then table B

Tags: mysql

I have two tables as bellow,

table A:

```
+------+----------------+
| TYPE | EMAIL          |
+------+----------------+
| 0    | test1@mail.com |
| 1    | test2@mail.com |
| 2    | test3@mail.com |
```

table B:

```
+------+----------------+
| ID   | EMAIL          |
+------+----------------+
| 1    | test1@mail.com |
| 2    | test4@mail.com |
| 3    | test5@mail.com |
```

I need to check the email address from both table with following criteria,

1. Check in the table A, IF EXISTS select the TYPE
2. IF it is not in table A, then check it in table B select the ID
3. even it is not in table B empty results as normal select query

I can do this with two quires, But my question is whether there is any possibility to do it with one single query ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope question is clear, if not please comment I will explain further.

Comment: There is something fundamentally wrong in the design of your database. Better to fix that than write a work around

Comment: you cant do these checks using mysql however you can do a union and and almost serve the purpose you are looking at.

Comment: @EdHeal yes it would be, But this is an existing database, I just need to collect some information..

Comment: @Abhik Thanks, I will try it and let you know..

Comment: Don't be afraid of using 2 queries. There's nothing wrong about it, even performance wise. Especially in this case when your result set will be different from different tables (``TYPE`` vs ``ID``).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternative: I hope it can be useful anyway.

```
(SELECT NULL AS ID, EMAIL, TYPE FROM A WHERE EMAIL=<email>)
UNION
(SELECT ID, EMAIL, NULL AS TYPE FROM B WHERE EMAIL=<email>)
```

In your application you will retrieve from 0 to 2 results. If you got 1 result, use it (note that you will have a NULL value in ID or TYPE). If you got 2 results, use the one where the TYPE is not NULL.

Using your dataset and "test1@mail.com" as the query parameter, this would be the result of the query:

```
ID    EMAIL           TYPE
NULL  test1@mail.com  0
1     test1@mail.com  NULL
```

Comment: exactly how I tried, thanks, as info I include the table name for select query as select 't1',id .....